# Animate absolute div to left:0 then to right:0 and loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, absolute

Ok, I know how to animate div's and loop the animation and stuff but this really got on my nerves, I want to animate a div to `left:0;` and then to `right:0;` and loop the animation and IT WILL NOT WORK like this...Why is that?

How do I do this?..

PS: Apparently jquery can't animate an absolute container from left:0 to right:o...but how can I get the desired animation?

Example:

Something like this will not work...:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
function animateMydiv() {
$('#mydiv').animate({'left':'0px'},6000).animate({'right':'0px'},6000, animateMydiv); 
}

animateMydiv();
});
```

**Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/bc927afp/).**

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for your code?

Comment: @emergence Just a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand positioning in CSS, you can't have both a `right` and a `left` value set at the same time.

So I would propose the follow. Just move it to the end of the document minus the width of the element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var width = $(document).width() - $('#mydiv').width();

  function animateMydiv() {
    $('#mydiv').animate({'left': width + 'px'}, 6000).animate({'left': '0px'}, 6000);

  }

  animateMydiv();

});
```

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bc927afp/1/

And if you want it to be endless, leave the function as you had in your example:
`$('#mydiv').animate({'left': width + 'px'}, 6000).animate({'left': '0px'}, 6000, animateMydiv);`

Comment: That's just what I was writing right now :)) and yes, you can have left and right value set to 0 at the same time, and if you add a margin: auto it will place the div center page but that's not the point, I also tried when left was 0 , right was auto and the other way around but it didn't work ^^ Anyway, this works nicely, Thanks ! +1 and Accept !

Comment: Thanks. (You can also use `margin: auto` without `position: absolute` though)

Comment: Well, i know, but in order for a div to be centered on page and you needed it to have position:absolute, you would have to add left:0; right:0; margin:auto; ... if you didn't need it to be absolute and it works just as well with relative, then margin:0 auto; will do the trick :D

Answer (score 0):

As was already said in another answer: you basically can not animate from `left` to `right`. So the key to solving this, is by only using one of them.

Start position on the left:

```
left: 0%;
transform: translationY(0%);
```

End position on the right:

```
left: 100%;
transform: translationY(-100%);
```

All you have to do now is to animate the `left` and the `transform` properties. I recently wrote down a more detailed explanation and also showcased a CSS-based animation at https://medium.com/@taig/dynamically-position-and-center-an-html-element-with-css-based-on-percentage-5fea0799a589.